# Is this possible to connect microsoft database from iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sql-server

I would like to connect microsoft database via iPhone, is that possible to do so? Is there any third party library required? If not, any suggestions on that?? Thank you.

Comment: Are you planning to embed the database on the phone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone connect to SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033369/iphone-connect-to-sql-server)

Comment: I want to connect a remote SQL server.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you don't want the SQL Server to be installed on the iPhone...

In any other case the DB should be installed on your server. You should provide a set of web services (e.g. ASP.NET) and communicate with these web services from the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a web service for the data that the iPhone connects to.